# PHP - Get array of objects from query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

Simplified version of the problem:

So I have this query which is inside a function.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

How I want to use mysql_fetch_object() to get an object from a row.

Because in the end I wanted to get an array of objects I do this:

```
while ($a[] = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { // empty here }
```

In the end the function just returns $a. And it works almost fine.

My problem is that mysql_fetch_object will return at the end a NULL "row" (which is normal because the result ended but I still assigned it to the array).

Any ideas on how to do this in a decent way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you could move the assignment from the while condition to the while body like:

```
<?php
while ($entry = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   $a[] = $entry;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_object` actually returns `FALSE` if there are no more rows. I would do this:

```
$a = array();
while (($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) !== FALSE) {
  $a[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I've always considered the type checking good practice when dealing with boolean return values in PHP. In this case it won't matter, but it numerous others, it most certainly does. It's a defensive programming practice, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
array_pop($a);
```

after the `while`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Comment: Not generally advised, but since this will always be there because that is the exit condition on the loop, this is a reasonable solution. I'd add a comment explaining why you are `array_pop`ing though.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems like duplicate of [how to fetch all the row of the result in php mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940332/how-to-fetch-all-the-row-of-the-result-in-php-mysql)

```
//Database Connection
$sqlConn =  new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

//Build SQL String
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

//Execute the query and put data into a result
$result = $this->sqlConn->query($sqlString);

//Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Copy result into a numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

//Copy result into both a associative and numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```