# how to fetch all the row of the result in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

In my table I have 2 records with `companyid = 1` , but when I run the php below for `companyid = 1` it returns only the first one !
How can I fetch all the records?

The php file:

```
if (isset($_GET["companyid"])) {
$companyid = $_GET['companyid'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`         
                        WHERE companyid = $companyid;");

if (!empty($result)) {      

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $product = array();
      $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
      $product["productname"] = $row["productname"];        
    }

   $response["product"] = array();

       array_push($response["product"], $product);

        // success
       $response["success"] = 1;

   echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no product JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Using `mysql_fetch_array` is happening the same. 
it returns `{"product":[{"pid":"12371","productname":"test"}],"success":1}` 
when i run a query without parameters `select * from table` using `mysql_fetch_array` it returns all the rows ..

Comment: You need to loop through the results and read in each row.  Change your if (mysql_num_rows...) call to a for loop.

Comment: don't do `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` you're destroying your `$result` data when you do that. rename it `$row` or something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch all rows based on the query into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931684/fetch-all-rows-based-on-the-query-into-an-array)

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also, if you're using PDO you can just call `fetchAll` and be done with it :)

Comment: @orourkek I totally take your point and agree - to a point. Some of us have to maintain old code in deprecated code bases which necessitates learning out of date mysql_* functions for the sake of consistency. I'm no fan of these functions and much prefer PDO or mysqli but there is no escaping the need to know this old stuff.

Answer (score 35):

As  NikiC pointed out you should not be using the mysql_ functions any longer, you can fetch the entire array in both PDO and mysqli, Here is a example to fetch all rows using the [mysqli->fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function, hope this helps!

```
//Database Connection
$sqlConn =  new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

//Build SQL String
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

//Execute the query and put data into a result
$result = $sqlConn->query($sqlString);

//Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Copy result into a numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

//Copy result into both a associative and numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Comment: fetch_all didn't initially work on ubuntu for me - I needed to do: sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd and restart apache

Comment: `$result = $this->sqlConn->query($sqlString);` did not work for me, I had to use `$result = $sqlConn->query($sqlString);`

Comment: @amurrell I had to install php5-mysqlnd as well, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

[php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

I would recommend you to use PDO instead of mysql_

```
if (!empty($result)) {
```

Could be `is_resource($result)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through the result to pull all the rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
//Do stuff 
}
```

On a side note, you should be using at least mysqli or PDO instead of mysql_* functions.

Comment: I have edited the php code above.. using the loop I still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe the batch processing with Doctrine or any kind of iterations with MySQL (PDO or mysqli) are just an illusion.

@dimitri-k provided a nice explanation especially about unit of work. The problem is the miss leading: "**$query->iterate()**" which doesn't really iterate over the data source. It's **just an \Traversable wrapper** around already **fully fetched** data source.

An example demonstrating that even removing Doctrine abstraction layer completely from the picture, we will still run into **memory issues**:

```
echo 'Starting with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";

$pdo  = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=HOST", "USER", "PW");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_big_table LIMIT 100000');
$stmt->execute();

while ($rawCampaign = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // echo $rawCampaign['id'] . "\n";
}

echo 'Ending with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";
```

**Output:**

```
Starting with memory usage: 6 MB 
Ending with memory usage: 109.46875 MB
```

Here, the disappointing **getIterator()** method:

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $data = $this->fetchAll();

    return new \ArrayIterator($data);
}
```

You can use my little library to **actually** stream heavy tables using PHP Doctrine or DQL or just pure SQL. However you find appropriate: https://github.com/EnchanterIO/remote-collection-stream