# How to create an array of mysql results which have certain value in their row

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$pollid=$_GET['pollid'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT question FROM questions where survey_id="' . $pollid . '"');
$question = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $pollid;
echo $question;

?>
```

And it will echo first question which has survey_id=$pollid. But I want to make an array of all the questions, which have survey_id=$pollid.How I can do that?

Comment: Seriously :| mysql_result!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fetch all the row of the result in php mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940332/how-to-fetch-all-the-row-of-the-result-in-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the results and add them to an array:

```
$pollid = (int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT question FROM questions where survey_id="' . $pollid . '"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $questions[$pollid] = $row['question '];
}
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**. In my example I casted `$_GET['pollid']` to an integer to help protect against them. A better approach would be to use prepared statements as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mysqli_ instead of mysql_,

```
// MYSQLI
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'example', 'example', 'test');

print '<h3>MYSQLI: simple select</h3>';
$rs = $mysqli->query( YOUR SELECT QUERY);
while($row = $rs->fetch_object())
{
    //DATA
}
```