# Display all column entries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to display all column entries in a database in a for-loop using PHP.

This is what I have so far:

```
$zulassungsnummerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Zulassungsnummer FROM sb_fern_course");
$zulassungsnummer = mysql_fetch_array($zulassungsnummerQuery);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($zulassungsnummer) ; $i++) {
  echo $zulassungsnummer["Zulassungsnummer"][i];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit ---------------------------------------------------------------------

I solved it like this, but now I have another problem. I only want echo out the entries != Null but it won't work in my approach. I still get all the empty columns..

Is there any other way to achieve this?

```
$zulassungsnummerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Zulassungsnummer FROM sb_fern_course");

while($zulassungsnummer = mysql_fetch_array($zulassungsnummerQuery))
{
  if(!empty($zulassungsnummer) && !is_null($zulassungsnummer) && $zulassungsnummer !== '' ){
    echo "<li>".$zulassungsnummer['Zulassungsnummer']."</li>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a `for` loop?

Comment: 1. You are only fetching 1 row and 2. you are using a deprecated mysql api.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940332/how-to-fetch-all-the-row-of-the-result-in-php-mysql

Comment: why don't u use foreach loop?

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look at it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only process the first row of your result - if this is not desirable, you would need to enclose your for loop with another loop to cycle through all rows of the result.
2. You only have one column listed in your query - if you want more of them, you need to change the query to `SELECT * FROM sb_fern_course` or list all the needed columns explicitly.
3. The body of for-loop should be `echo $zullassungsnummer[$i];`
4. You are using `mysql_*` functions, that are removed from PHP starting with version 7.0. For future-proofing your code, switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

---

Reply to edited question: You need to check the emptiness of `$zulassungsnummer['Zulassungsnummer']`:

```
if(!empty($zulassungsnummer['Zulassungsnummer'])) {
  echo "<li>".$zulassungsnummer['Zulassungsnummer']."</li>";
}
```

But you may be better off dealing with this filtering on the query level:

```
SELECT Zulassungsnummer FROM sb_fern_course
WHERE Zulassungsnummer IS NOT NULL AND Zulassungsnummer <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$zulassungsnummerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Zulassungsnummer FROM sb_fern_course");
$zulassungsnummer = mysql_fetch_array($zulassungsnummerQuery);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($zulassungsnummer) ; $i++) {
  echo $zulassungsnummer[$i] ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following loop

```
while($zulassungsnummer = mysql_fetch_array($zulassungsnummerQuery))
{
    //Manipulate results
}
```

Comment: **You are using mysql_* functions, that are removed from PHP starting with version 7**

Comment: If my server is still using old php, and I am not planning for a php upgrade? It all depends of finance...