# Reading data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

If you input in **text_username** is same in *username* -values in my table- the browser will echo **Correct** but if the **text_username** is not the same values in **-values in my table-** the browser will echo **Wrong**. That will be shown in browser but the code that will read is the first row in my table but in the second one will not read. Thanks in advance

For example I have values in my table that the Username is dave, then if I click the button, the browser will enter correct, but I have username in my table that spencer, then if i input that browser it will echo wrong.

PS: I edit this question.

Here's the structure:

```
$reservation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from reservation");
//qwe is the button
    $username = $_POST['text_username'];
    if(isset($_POST['qwe']) && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($reservation))
    {
        if($row['username'] == $username) 
        {
            echo "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong";
        }
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Why not just query the database with `WHERE username=....`? Using prepared statements, of course..

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484638/1155833) and welcome to SO. Please have a read of [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should be researched and/or explain what the problem is. Also you should show us what you tried, what did(n't) work and what you expected. That would help us help you.

Comment: As is this will just be comparing the first row in your DB. You would need to loop the fetch, but using a `where` will be much more efficient.

Comment: @chris85 I already did your advised, its finally working. But the problem now when you enter is not equal in values in my table the else statement will not work.

Here's the structure: 
  $username = $_POST['text_username'];
 $reservation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from reservation  WHERE username = '$username'");

    if(isset($_POST['qwe']) && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reservation))
    {
        if($row['username'] == $username) 
        {
            echo "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
         $error = "wrong";
         echo $error;
        }
      }

Comment: @Dave Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it Wrong You forget to add 'where' keyword in  the query
Where keyword is used find particular row with particular value in particular column

```
if(isset($_POST['qwe'])){

        if(!empty($_POST['text_username']))
        {
$username = $_POST['text_username'];
$reservation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from reservation where username='$username'");     
            if(mysqli_num_rows($reservation)) 
            {
                echo "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Wrong";
            }
          }
}
         ?>
```

Comment: I did this but the else statement is not working, but the if statement will be working.

Comment: @Dave what is $_POST["que"]

Comment: that one is the button

Comment: why? please help me out of this problem thank @prince

Comment: @Dave Try now With Updated Answer

Comment: @Dave  If you found my answer helpful then mark it correct