# Call sql function with php

Tags: php, sql, function

I have a SQL function that returns a string value, and I want to call this via php. Should be easy, but after two days I have made little progress.

So for testing I created a function called **testString** within Namcheap's phpMyAdmin that just returns a string, and it *works* when I run it on the namecheap server:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` FUNCTION `testString`(`yo` INT) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
  NO SQL
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
  return "this is a string"$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In php I am able to open the database select, get values, etc. No problem, however I cannot successfully call a function. When I try I get a boolean type rather than a string:

```
$stringQuery = "SELECT testString();";
$stringResult = $con->query($stringQuery);
echo "Type:".gettype($stringResult)."<br>";
```

Type:boolean

### How do I call this function from php?

thanks to @Mehdi I did figure out that the user was not granted permission to execute a function, so I granted permission and now it returns an object rather than a boolean. OK, how do I extract the text string from this object?

Comment: Are you using PDO or Mysqli? can you do `var_dump($stringReult)`

Comment: It should be detailed further. We don't know what $con stands for

Comment: @Flimzy: namecheap is the hosting provider, and while I understand the question is not necessarily namecheap specific - I am new to php/sql I don't know all the differences between nc's version and std.  I thought adding it might provide useful. If not, ignore it.

Comment: @Mehdi: bool(false), so presumably the call is not working. If I execute the statement "SELECT testString();" in MySQL Workbench it works, btw.

Comment: @Rinsad Ahmed: fair enough. Let me put it this way, this call works: $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM someTable;");    and returns an object with all the table values. Works like a champ, can extract values like crazy.

Comment: You didn't answer my other question, are you using PDO or Mysqli? try printing errors after executing the query.

Comment: @Mehdi, oops, sorry.  Mysqli.  At the top of the php the two lines   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
 are both present, however no errors are displayed. Or do you mean some other error reporting method?

Comment: [Use mysqli_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: in the index.php file (this is a web page, btw) I executed the command echo $con->error;  It returned with "execute command denied to user 'user_SQLread'@'localhost' for routine 'user_sampleDeck.testString'  "

Comment: var_dump($stringResult); object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: To fetch the results [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484638/2595450)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off just dumping the entire thing.

```
$stringQuery = "SELECT testString();";
$stringResult = $con->query($stringQuery);
var_dump($stringResult->fetch_all());
```

or

```
var_dump($stringResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting to this this simple answer was torture. Thank you @Mehdi for some guidance. I never imagined something this simple could be so complicated.

So, if you have a mySQL function that outputs a string, and you want to retrieve that string value via php, try this php code (troubleshooting lines commented out):

```
  $stringQuery = "SELECT testString();"; //testString is the function name.
  $stringResult = $con->query($stringQuery);
  //echo "<br>error: ".$con->error."<br>";
  //var_dump($stringResult);
  $resultArray = $stringResult->fetch_assoc();
  //var_dump($resultArray);
  echo $resultArray["testString()"]; //the function output.
```

If there is a more direct way of achieving this result, please share.

**Edit: Here is a very direct way (although harder to parse out):

```
$stringVal = $con->query("SELECT testString();")->fetch_assoc()["testString()"];
```

obviously if you are passing a value to the function, it would go in the  parenthesis, as testString(1).