# How do you fetch from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to any type of programming or coding. I'm not quite understanding why no matter what adjustments I make to my php file I can't seem to pull any data from a table.

Here is a link to the table: https://i.gyazo.com/4ad5e860895014c49dbe0539c38cdec2.png

Above is the test table I have been trying to use. From what I can understand I'm connecting to the database okay, but all of my problems come after the connection. Also, I'm using php 7.0 so a lot of the information I'm finding online has not been helpful.

If there is something glaringly wrong with my table or in my code, please let me know.
Here is my code: 
'''

```
//Set Variables
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "test";

//Create Connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$password,$databaseName);

//Check Connection
if(!$connection){

    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());

}

echo "Connected successfully <br>";

//Fetch Data
$query = "SELECT * from table1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ($row[1], $row[2]);

mysqli_free_result($result);


mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Change `$row[1], $row[2]` to `$row['id'], $row['sex']`

Comment: Or better still @SimoneRossaini Change `$row[1], $row[2]` to `$row[0], $row[1]`

Comment: Right @RiggsFolly ^^

Comment: And change `printf(...)` to `echo $row[0] . ' '  . $row[1];`

Comment: You also have 2 rows in `table1` So you will need to fetch these rows in the WHILE loop as per almost all examples in the manual

Comment: You may also use `var_dump($row);` to check the contents of the `$row` variable.

Comment: If you don’t have proper PHP error reporting enabled, then please go do that first of all now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fetch all the row of the result in php mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940332/how-to-fetch-all-the-row-of-the-result-in-php-mysql)

Comment: I only have warnings. So, everything should function properly if my code was correct, but it is not. 

https://gyazo.com/0e264975c1cfd00f9a7b3deee47d6bc7

Comment: One more thing that may actually be helpful, with the rows currently defined as they are (I know I will need a while loop to iterate through multiple rows, but trying to see if I can even pull one from the table) after doing a var dump it actually returned that the value of the row was null. Does that mean my $row definition is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue a few hours ago. The code I had posted would have worked perfectly fine if I was connecting to the port for MySQL rather than MariaDB. Didn't realize that the port that MariaDB was connected to was the default.

MariaDB by default was port 3306, but MySQL was 3308. After specifying 'localhost:3308' I was able to start properly pulling rows from my tables.